# How to insert item in list at given index in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, list, insert

I am working on a `c++` code where I need to insert an item at a given index of a list. I have two list :

```
list <int> objectIdList;  //This list will save id's of object
list <double> objectIdDtimeList;  //This list will save time duration of each particular object id.
```

I have a code from where I am saving all the object id's in `objectIdList` which looks like below:

```
Index    Value
[0]      3
[1]      6
[2]      2
```

Now I need to save time duration of these object id's (3, 6, 2) in `objectIdDtimeList`. My plan is to save the time duration in list at index which is the object id. For example, for object id `3`, its total time duration will be saved in the list at index `3`. For object id `6`, its time duration will be saved at index 6.

To do this, I planned to use `list.insert()` as below:

```
time_t start, end;
time(&start);

/*
 * SOME CODE HERE
 * SOME CODE HERE
*/

for (auto id : objectIdList)
{
    time(&end);
    double time_passed = difftime(current, start);  //Getting the time duration in seconds

    list<int>::iterator it = objectIdList.begin();

    advance(it, id);  // iterator to point to object id index

    objectIdDtimeList.insert(it, time_passed);
}
```

But above code is giving below error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::list<_Ty, _Alloc>::insert [with _Ty=double, _Alloc=std::allocator<double>]" matches the argument list

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>> std::list<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>::insert(std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>,unsigned __int64,const _Ty &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>' to 'std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>'
```

Is there any way I can achieve this functionality. Is there any other alternative to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two different iterator types here.

```
list<int>::iterator it = objectIdList.begin();
```

This is an iterator into `objectIdList` but in order to call `objectIdDtimeList.insert(...)`, you need an iterator into `objectIdDtimeList`. Hence, try changing the above line into

```
auto it = objectIdDtimeList.begin();
```

Advancing the right iterator with `id` should still work, and the insertion should succeed.